# deleting last child issue if more than one child exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

**SOLUTION**

```
removeChild: function(select) {
    $(select).nextAll().remove();
}
```

---

I am trying to dynamically create a chain of `<select>` boxes, here is an example function:

**JQUERY:**

```
getLanguages: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: './db_scripts/get_languages.php',
        success: function( data ) {
            $('<select>', {
                id: 'languages',
                html: createOptions( data,'Language' )
            }).appendTo('#sidebar');
        }
    });
},

selects.getLanguages();
$('#languages').live('change', function() {
    selects.removeChild($(this));
    selects.getCategories();    
});
```

My **HTML** is just:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Adding selects work perfectly. What I am trying to do is have another function that removes any children underneath the select that was changed. This way it removes all children `<select>` and the user can change the selection process anywhere in `<select>` tree. Here is an example of it working (try changing a top level option) http://philipimperato.com/mobileOrder

here is my `removeChild()` function:

```
removeChild: function(select) {
        alert('This is what is being passed in: ' + $(select).attr('id'));
        alert('This is the last child of the div, #sidebar: ' + $(select).parent('div').children('select:last-child').attr('id'));
        while($(select).parent('div').children('select:last-child') != $(select)) {
            alert('Same as first: ' + $(select).attr('id') + 'Same as 2nd: ' +$(select).parent('div').children('select:last-child').attr('id'));
            $(select).parent('div').remove($(select).parent('div').children('select:last-child'));
        }
    }
```

I have alerted stuff out for you convenience: Here is the website: [InsanelyWeb](http://InsanelyWeb.com)

The function is not working and giving me a jQuery error: "c.replace is not a function" - I have no idea how to fix that. Does anyone have any advice for me? Thanks!
**EDIT**

---

Here is the function working in plain javascript (which I just figure out)

```
while(el.parentNode.lastChild != el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode.lastChild);
}
```

I am trying to convert that to jquery to do more stuff like `hide()` etc

```
while($(el).parent('div').children('select:last-child') != el) {
            $($(el).parent('div').children('select:last-child')).remove();
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do in `removeChild`. Do you want to remove the selected element in `select`?

Comment: No, I want to remove all the `<select>` elements below it.

Comment: what is "it" in your "below it", `#sidebar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do in `removeChild`, but looking at your code, I think you misunderstood the way [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) works in jQuery. It removed the elements selected (as in by the selector). So, if you want to remove the `select` element in `removeChild`, you can simply do:

```
$(select).remove();
```

Another method that also removes elements from the DOM is [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), which removes all children of the selected elements. So, if you want to remove all children of the `#sidebar`, you could do:

```
$('#sidebar').empty();
```

**EDIT**:

Okay, here's my 2nd try :)

```
removeChild: function(select) {
    $(select).nextAll().remove();
}
```

Take a look at [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/). It may be what you are after.

Comment: Okay, I think you might have solved it. In `removeChild` I am trying to remove all the `<select>` elements that were created that are AFTER the `<select>` that was changed. Therefore, `empty()` would not work. I have updated my question with (what I think) is the final issue

Comment: I think I got what you want to do! It seems like you found your solution. Is there any other problem?

Comment: Yes, I can't do it in `jQuery` check my code at the bottom of the question. The passed in element and the last child are not equal even though they are :( I think it has to do with one being a jquery element and the only just being a javascript element, but I don't know

Comment: Hahaha, I am so... mad, yet happy that the edited solution worked. Thank you very much. Freakin' jQuery... and it's brilliance

Comment: You just gotta love jQuery ;)